# set function $G＝f-g$, then $f≦P$ and $g≦N$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I want to prove the following statement.

Let $G$ be a set function, and let its Jordan decomposition $G＝P-N$.If $G$ can be written like $G＝f-g$ using finite measure $f,g$,
then $f≦P$ and $g≦N$.

I assumed that $P＜f$ and $N＜g$,but I couldn't find contradiction.I may use finiteness of measure,$f,g$.Thank you for your help.Hints or references are also appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused by what you mean by "set function". Do you mean signed measure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is clearly false. Let $\mu$ a signed measure on $(X, \mathcal{M})$, let $\mu = \alpha - \beta$ be its Jordan decomposition, suppose that both $\alpha, \beta$ are finite. Let $x \in X$ and suppose $\{x\} \in \mathcal{M}$. Let $\lambda$ be measure on $(X,\mathcal M)$ given by the Dirac mass at $x$, i.e. $\lambda(E) = 1_{E}(x)$. Then $\mu = (\alpha + \lambda) - (\beta + \lambda)$, and clearly it is not the case that $\alpha + \lambda \leq \alpha.$

Note that really the opposite statement holds, as you can read about on the pertinent [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn_decomposition_theorem#Jordan_measure_decomposition). Namely if $\mu = \alpha - \beta$ is the Jordan decomposition and $\mu = \gamma - \lambda$ then $\alpha \leq \gamma, \beta \leq \lambda$ where $\gamma, \lambda$ are positive measures.